# How to add column with constant in Spark-java data frame

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have imported

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
```

in my Java-Spark driver

But

```
DataFrame inputDFTwo = hiveContext.sql("select * from sourcing_src_tbl");
inputDFTwo.withColumn("asofdate", lit("2016-10-2"));
```

here "lit" is still showing error in eclipse(windows).Which library should I include to make it work.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Most likely that `lit` is not defined, which is indeed the case here :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Either import object like you do know and use it to access method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

df.withColumn("foo", functions.lit(1));
```

or use `import static` and call method directly:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

df.withColumn("foo", lit(1));
```